# When HP is 100, player doesn't pick up recovery items

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a FPS in Unity.

How can I prevent the player from picking up recovery items when the player's HP is 100 (full)?
Currently, players can pick up recovery items even when their HP is full, and I want to limit the conditions for getting them.
The first thing I can think of is to temporarily disable the collision on the recovery item side, when the player's HP is 100.

I want to use `collider.enabled = false;` in an if statement, how do I write it?
Or am I doing it wrong?

Please surpport me.

*HPItem.cs (This is a HPItem)*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HPItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public FPSController fPSController;

    public int reward = 100;

    public AudioClip getSound;
     <summary>
     </summary>
    <param name="collision"></param>

        [SerializeField]
    public Vector3 speed;


    void Start()
    {

        fPSController = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FPSController>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(getSound,transform.position);
            Destroy(gameObject, getSound.length);

            fPSController.AddHP(reward);
        }
    }
    
}
```

*FPSController.cs(This is a Player)*

```
int playerHP = 100, maxPlayerHP = 100;
public Slider hpBer;

public void AddHP(int amount)
    {
        playerHP += amount;

        if (playerHP > 100)
        {
            playerHP = 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I want to use collider.enabled = false; in an if statement` .. then do that ...?

Answer (score 2):

It would not be better to check the onTriggerEnter function, once you know that it is the player you check the value of life, if it is 100 you do not collect it

Comment: Do I need to add a new method to pick up the HP value from the player for GetComponent?

Comment: I would like to know specific examples, so can someone please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Check the health of the player when the collision happens, only collect if health is not full.

Not a perfect solution (i.e. if player loses health while standing on the health item, they won't pick it up), but you could use `OnTriggerStay()` for that.

FPSController.cs:

```
// Add public getter for heath
public int Health => playerHP;
```

HPItem.cs:

```
...
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // Add check for health to this if statement.
    // && statements are evaluated left to right, so
    // no danger of NullReferenceException
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" &&
        other.GetComponent<FPSController>().Health != 100)
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(getSound,transform.position);
        Destroy(gameObject, getSound.length);

        fPSController.AddHP(reward);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: The code you suggested worked effectively for my situation. I appreciate your help.

I had already introduced the `int playerHP` variable in FPSController.cs for myself, but I wasn't familiar with the fact that `health =>` can be called using `&&` on the recovery item side.

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: A prroblem has arisen.
When the player's HP value is below 100, the player will not recover even if they get a recovery item.
How can I fix this?
I'm using `int` for the player HP value and `Slider` for the HP display, are these the problem?

Comment: It solved the problem by adding the following to the method. Thank you.
 `hpBer.value = playerHP;`

Comment: This topic has been completely resolved. Thank you all for your supports.